# How to make an authenticated call to the youtube API without oauth?

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, google-api-ruby-client

I'm writing a job that will consume some youtube stats and dump them in our database.

While it was a bit of a pain to get oauth all set up, I have it making authenticated calls. However, I want to do this in the background without a browser window opening / requiring access.

When I've tried to initialize the Google API client with an API key it fails saying "ArgumentError: Missing access token."

Comment: You cannot make an authenticated call without user acceptance, at least one time, of the oAuth flow ... that's the whole principle behind oAuth (The user has to grant explicit permission). However, you can create your app in such a way that, the first time a user does this, you capture not only the returned access token, but also a refresh token ... store the refresh token in your database and then on future visits by the user, you can use that refresh token to get an access token without them having to go through the oAuth flow again.

Comment: Since we'd be the only user, it sounds like this would be a great approach. Can you point me to an example where someone is grabbing and storing these tokens?